# I'm facing an issue with exoplayer and lazycolumn to achieve functionality like Instagram reels

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my code I have created an exoplayer singleton, and prepared all the media items before the lazy column initialised. But it lags when you scroll.

Can anyone please guide me how to optimise my code so I can achieve functionality like Instagram reels.

I have shared my code file.

And I have tried to remember playerview so it can not change and give me appropriate result but it's not worked.

Thanks

```
package com.app.myapplication.component

import android.content.Context

import android.view.ViewGroup

import android.widget.FrameLayout

import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes

import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas

import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi

import androidx.compose.foundation.Image

import androidx.compose.foundation.background

import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior

import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.snapping.rememberSnapFlingBehavior

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width

import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn

import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState

import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState

import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape

import androidx.compose.material.CircularProgressIndicator

import androidx.compose.material.Divider

import androidx.compose.material.Icon

import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme

import androidx.compose.material.Text

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect

import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect

import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableIntState

import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue

import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableIntStateOf

import androidx.compose.runtime.remember

import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment

import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip

import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap

import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext

import androidx.compose.ui.res.imageResource

import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource

import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView

import androidx.media3.common.C

import androidx.media3.common.MediaItem

import androidx.media3.common.PlaybackException

import androidx.media3.common.Player

import androidx.media3.common.Player.Listener

import androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi

import androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource

import androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayer

import androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ConcatenatingMediaSource

import androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaSource

import androidx.media3.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout

import androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView

import coil.compose.rememberAsyncImagePainter

import com.app.myapplication.R

import com.app.myapplication.component.exoplayer.ResizeMode

import com.app.myapplication.core.extensions.defaultPadding

import com.app.myapplication.core.extensions.horizontalPadding

import com.app.myapplication.core.extensions.iconSize

import com.app.myapplication.core.extensions.verticalPadding

import com.app.myapplication.core.util.ExoPlayerState

import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope

import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)

@Composable

fun MiReels(

    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,

    showControl: Boolean = false,

    resizableMode: ResizeMode = ResizeMode.RESIZE_MODE_FIT,

    layoutParam: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

    ),

    horizontalAlignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,

    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical = Arrangement.Center,

    onIdle: @Composable () -> Unit,

    onReady: @Composable (ExoPlayer) -> Unit,

    onBuffer: @Composable () -> Unit,

    onEnd: @Composable () -> Unit,

) {

    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    val flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState = lazyListState)

    Box(modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Black)) {

        println("!@# MiReels")

        ReelsHeader()

        ReelsList(

            modifier = modifier,

            showControl = showControl,

            resizableMode = resizableMode,

            layoutParam = layoutParam,

            horizontalAlignment = horizontalAlignment,

            verticalArrangement = verticalArrangement,

            lazyListState = lazyListState,

            flingBehavior = flingBehavior,

            onBuffer = onBuffer,

            onReady = onReady,

            onIdle = onIdle,

            onEnd = onEnd

        )

    }

}

@Composable

fun ReelsHeader() {

    Row(

        modifier = Modifier

            .fillMaxWidth()

            .defaultPadding(),

        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween

    ) {

        println("!@# ReelsHeader")

        Text(stringResource(id = R.string.text_reels), color = Color.White)

        Icon(

            ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.ic_outlined_camera),

            tint = Color.White,

            modifier = Modifier.iconSize(),

            contentDescription = ""

        )

    }

}

@androidx.annotation.OptIn(UnstableApi::class)

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)

@Composable

private fun ReelsList(

    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,

    showControl: Boolean = false,

    resizableMode: ResizeMode = ResizeMode.RESIZE_MODE_FIT,

    layoutParam: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

    ),

    horizontalAlignment: Alignment.Horizontal = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,

    verticalArrangement: Arrangement.Vertical = Arrangement.Center,

    lazyListState: LazyListState,

    flingBehavior: FlingBehavior,

    onIdle: @Composable () -> Unit,

    onReady: @Composable (ExoPlayer) -> Unit,

    onBuffer: @Composable () -> Unit,

    onEnd: @Composable () -> Unit,

) {

    println("!@# ReelsList")

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val reels = listOf(

        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4",

        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4",

        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4",

        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4",

        "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerMeltdowns.mp4"

    )

    var currentVideoIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    val exoPlayer = remember {

        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()

    }

    val exoPlayerState = remember {

        mutableIntStateOf(ExoPlayerState.DEFAULT.value)

    }

    val listener: Listener = PlayerListener(exoPlayerState)

    val playerState by exoPlayerState

    PlayerState(playerState, exoPlayer = exoPlayer, onBuffer, onEnd, onIdle, onReady)

    DisposableEffect(

        reels[currentVideoIndex]

    ) {

        exoPlayer.apply {

            println("!@# ReelsList DisposableEffect")

            val mediaSources = reels.map { uri ->

                val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)

                val dataSource = dataSourceFactory.createDataSource()

                val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)

                ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)

                    .createMediaSource(mediaItem)

            }

            val concatenatingMediaSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource(true)

            concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSources(mediaSources)

            setMediaSource(concatenatingMediaSource)

            prepare()

            addListener(listener)

            videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING

            repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE

        }

        // Delay the release of ExoPlayer by a few seconds

        onDispose {

            exoPlayer.stop()

            exoPlayer.clearMediaItems()

            exoPlayer.clearVideoSurface()

        }

    }

    // Use LaunchedEffect to listen for changes in the first visible item index

    LaunchedEffect(lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex) {

        currentVideoIndex = lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex

    }

    LazyColumn(

        state = lazyListState,

        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),

        flingBehavior = flingBehavior

    ) {

        items(reels.size) { index ->

            Box(

                modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxSize(),

            ) {

                Column(

                    modifier,

                    horizontalAlignment = horizontalAlignment,

                    verticalArrangement = verticalArrangement

                ) {

                    if (index == currentVideoIndex) {

                        val uri = reels[index]

                        VideoPlayer(

                            uri = uri,

                            showControl,

                            resizableMode,

                            layoutParam,

                            listener,

                            exoPlayer,

                            index

                        )

                    }

                }

                Column(

                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomStart),

                ) {

                    ReelFooter()

                    Divider()

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

@Composable

@Preview

fun ReelFooter() {

    Column(

        modifier = Modifier.defaultPadding(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center

    ) {

        // user data

        Row(

            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,

        ) {

            Image(

                painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter("reel.user.image"),

                contentDescription = null,

                modifier = Modifier

                    .size(20.dp)

                    .background(color = Color.Gray, shape = CircleShape)

                    .clip(CircleShape)

            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(horizontalPadding))

            Text(

                text = "reel.user.username",

                color = Color.White,

                style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2

            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(horizontalPadding))

            Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(5.dp), onDraw = {

                drawCircle(

                    color = Color.White, radius = 8f

                )

            })

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(horizontalPadding))

            Text(

                text = "Follow", color = Color.White, style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2

            )

        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(verticalPadding))

        // actions

        Row(

            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),

            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,

            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically

        ) {

            Row(

                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically

            ) {

                UserAction(R.drawable.ic_outlined_favorite)

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(horizontalPadding))

                UserAction(R.drawable.ic_outlined_comment)

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(horizontalPadding))

                UserAction(R.drawable.ic_share)

            }

            Row(

                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically

            ) {

                UserActionWithText(

                    drawableRes = R.drawable.ic_outlined_favorite, text = "10"

                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(horizontalPadding))

                UserActionWithText(

                    drawableRes = R.drawable.ic_outlined_favorite, text = "5"

                )

            }

        }

    }

}

@Composable

private fun UserAction(@DrawableRes drawableRes: Int) {

    Icon(

        ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = drawableRes),

        tint = Color.White,

        modifier = Modifier.iconSize(),

        contentDescription = ""

    )

}

@Composable

private fun UserActionWithText(

    @DrawableRes drawableRes: Int, text: String

) {

    Icon(

        ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = drawableRes),

        tint = Color.White,

        modifier = Modifier.size(18.dp),

        contentDescription = ""

    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(horizontalPadding / 2))

    Text(

        text = text, color = Color.White, style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2

    )

}

@Composable

private fun LoadingIndicator(modifier: Modifier) {

    Box(

        modifier = modifier, contentAlignment = Alignment.Center

    ) {

        CircularProgressIndicator(

            color = Color.Gray, strokeWidth = 2.dp

        )

    }

}

@Composable

private fun PlayerListener(exoPlayerState: MutableIntState): Listener {

    val listener: Listener = remember {

        object : Listener {

            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {

                when (playbackState) {

                    Player.STATE_IDLE -> {

                        exoPlayerState.value = ExoPlayerState.STATE_IDLE.value

                    }

                    Player.STATE_BUFFERING -> {

                        exoPlayerState.value = ExoPlayerState.STATE_BUFFERING.value

                    }

                    Player.STATE_READY -> {

                        exoPlayerState.value = ExoPlayerState.STATE_READY.value

                    }

                    Player.STATE_ENDED -> {

                        exoPlayerState.value = ExoPlayerState.STATE_ENDED.value

                    }

                }

            }

            override fun onPlayerError(error: PlaybackException) {

                println("!@# ERROR $${error.message}")

            }

        }

    }

    return listener

}

@Composable

private fun PlayerState(

    playerState: Int,

    exoPlayer: ExoPlayer?,

    onBuffer: @Composable () -> Unit,

    onEnd: @Composable () -> Unit,

    onIdle: @Composable () -> Unit,

    onReady: @Composable (ExoPlayer) -> Unit

) {

    when (playerState) {

        ExoPlayerState.STATE_BUFFERING.value -> {

            onBuffer()

        }

        ExoPlayerState.STATE_ENDED.value -> {

            onEnd()

        }

        ExoPlayerState.STATE_IDLE.value -> {

            onIdle()

        }

        ExoPlayerState.STATE_READY.value -> {

            exoPlayer?.let {

                onReady(it)

            }

        }

    }

}

@androidx.annotation.OptIn(androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi::class)

@Composable

private fun PlayerView(

    context: Context,

    showControl: Boolean,

    resizableMode: ResizeMode,

    exoPlayer: ExoPlayer,

    layoutParam: ViewGroup.LayoutParams

): PlayerView {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val playerView = remember {

        PlayerView(context).apply {

            hideController()

            useController = showControl

            player = exoPlayer

            layoutParams = layoutParam

            resizeMode = when (resizableMode) {

                ResizeMode.RESIZE_MODE_FILL -> {

                    AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL

                }

                ResizeMode.RESIZE_MODE_FIT -> {

                    AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT

                }

                ResizeMode.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM -> {

                    AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM

                }

                ResizeMode.RESIZE_MODE_FIX_HEIGHT -> {

                    AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_HEIGHT

                }

                ResizeMode.RESIZE_MODE_FIX_WIDTH -> {

                    AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_WIDTH

                }

            }

        }

    }

    DisposableEffect(key1 = true) {

        onDispose {

            playerView.player = null

        }

    }

    return playerView

}

@Composable

@androidx.annotation.OptIn(androidx.media3.common.util.UnstableApi::class)

fun VideoPlayer(

    uri: String,

    showControl: Boolean,

    resizableMode: ResizeMode,

    layoutParam: ViewGroup.LayoutParams,

    listener: Listener,

    exoPlayer: ExoPlayer,

    index: Int

) {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val playerView = PlayerView(

        context = context,

        showControl = showControl,

        resizableMode = resizableMode,

        exoPlayer = exoPlayer,

        layoutParam = layoutParam

    )

    AndroidView(factory = {

        println("!@# VideoPlayer AndroidView")

        playerView

    }, update = {

        exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true

    })

}
```

I tried to handle the exoplayer state and tried to create Android view for each item of the Lazycolumn.

Comment: Same here, built release mode but still laggy.